# how can I connect models in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I made 2 classes:

```
class Preprocess():
    def __init
     .....
    def forward 
     ....

class Model ():
    def __init
     .....
    def forward
```

I would like to do Preprocess before putting them into Model. Could you kindly tell me how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Why don't you just pass Preprocess() inside Model.forward()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could also use `torch.nn.Sequential` which has the following upsides:

- easier on the eyes
- one has to just pass the `inputs` instead of remembering to call `Preprocess` before it

Code being:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(Preprocess(), Model())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compose them:

```py
pre = Preprocess()
model = Model()

output = model(pre(input))
```